# 'Cannot be followed by..' error when implementing while loop

Tags: syntax

I am trying to implement the following (iterative) scheme (a preconditioned conjugate gradient method):

```
    (x = Table[1, {i, 8}], r = f - A*x, z = B*r, p = z;  
 While[Abs[r] > 0, a = Transpose[r]*z/(Transpose[p]*p) ; x = x + ap; 
  s = r; r = r + a*A*p; z = y; 
  z = B*r; \[Beta] = (Transpose[r]*z)/(Transpose[s]*y; 
     p = z + \[Beta]*p)]; x)
```

I have already predefined $8 \times 8$ matrices $A$ and $B$ and a vector $f$.  When I run this code, I get the following error:

> Syntax::sntxf: "(" cannot be followed by
>   "x=Table[1,{i,8}],r=f-A*x,z=B*r,p=z;While[Abs[r]>0,a=Transpose[r]*z/(Transpose[p]*p);x=x+ap;s=r;r=r+a*A*p;z=y;z=B*r;[Beta]=(Transpose[r]*z)/(Transpose[s]*y;p=z+[Beta]*p)];x)".

Initially I tried to implement the while loop as a function of the initial vector $x$:

```
pcg[x_]:=(x, r = f - A*x, z = B*r, p = z;  
   While[Abs[r] > 0, a = Transpose[r]*z/(Transpose[p]*p) ; x = x + ap; 
  s = r; r = r + a*A*p; z = y; 
  z = B*r; \[Beta] = (Transpose[r]*z)/(Transpose[s]*y; 
     p = z + \[Beta]*p)]; x)
```

but that lead to a similar error.

Could anyone help me implement this while loop? This is one of my first codes on Mathematica so I apologize if this question is especially basic.

Comment: the problem is not the `While` but the commas on the first line which should be semicolons.   BTW if `ap` is meant to be `a*p` make sure there is a space between.

Comment: Another issue I see is if `r` is a vector, `Abs[r]>0` is never true. Do you want every component >0 ? or the magnitude?

Comment: @george2079 I was going to use the magnitude of $r$ so I have amended it accordingly. However, now my code seems to just spit out whatever initial value of $x$ I give it.

Comment: Dot product should be used for matrices, not *. What is `y`?

Comment: @Stitch In this case I am using $y$ and $s$ as placeholders for $z$ and $r$ so that $\beta$ can be calculated

Comment: Well, in this case you need to use `y=z`, not `z=y`

Comment: whatever your conditional expression is in the `While` you should evaluate that on its own to see what you get. If its not `True` the loop is just skipped.